# Converting a 5 digit int into time

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

In a legacy system (SQL Server 2005)  I have a column that stores a 5 digit integer (ie 86340) as time. The legacy application shows 86340 as 23:59:00. I am unsure how how to translate that 5 digit integer into a date-time data type using SQL.

Comment: What time does a number such as 86340 represent?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b584ec869dfd7e38895642af1f3a5194

Comment: The modulo operator in T-SQL is `%`. The `TIMEFROMPARTS` function was added in SQL Server 2012 though, so you can't just build a `time` from the parts you calculate. Even in SQL  Server 2012 though I don't thing 63 minutes would be an acceptable minute component

Comment: @GordonLinoff did an edit to reflect your question.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I would love to use your answer, however as the other poster pointed out, TIMEFROMPARTS didn't exist in SQL Server 2005

Comment: Is [`time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) a suitable "date-time data type", or do you want it as a [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? If the latter, what date should it use? It is worth noting that `time`s are limited to values less than 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2012+ has [`TIMEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function:

> **TIMEFROMPARTS ( hour, minute, seconds, fractions, precision )**
>   Returns a time value for the specified time and with the specified precision.

Which is similiar to Excel's [`TIME`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TIME-function-9A5AFF99-8F7D-4611-845E-747D0B8D5457):

> **TIME(hour, minute, second)**

Excel version could handle values over 0-60 range:

> Minute    Required. A number from 0 to 32767 representing the minute. **Any value greater than 59 will be converted to hours and minutes.**

And SQL counterpart cannot do that.

---

It looks like that value is simply number of seconds so you could use:

```
 DECLARE @A1 INT =  86340;
 SELECT DATEADD(second, @A1,CAST('00:00:00' AS TIME));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e241a19cf1bf73abd19aef12a6961a0e)**

EDIT:

As SQL Server 2005 does not support `TIME` data type, you could use `DATETIME` instead and skip date part in application.

```
 DECLARE @A1 INT =  86340;
 SELECT DATEADD(second, @A1,CAST('00:00:00' AS DATETIME));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5dcae1cde7cc07226092f87679c358d5)**

Comment: I ran the SQL code and it works and the explication helps as well, so I am going with this as the accepted answer.  However to make it work I needed to change the CAST to datetime instead of time because the time data type doesn't exist in SQL Server 2005 (as I said this is a legacy system) .  If you could update the code sample that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value you have is an integer representation of the seconds since midnight, you have a couple of choices in SQL Server 2005. You can either render the value as a `VARCHAR`, which is readable, you can render it as `DATETIME`, which appends the date information, or you can maybe pull in a date from another field to get an meaningful `DATETIME` for your value.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATEADD(SECOND, 86340, 0), 114) AS [InVarchar];

+--------------+
|  InVarchar   |
+--------------+
| 23:59:00:000 |
+--------------+


SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 86340, 0) AS [InDatetime];

+-------------------------+
|       InDatetime        |
+-------------------------+
| 1900-01-01 23:59:00.000 |
+-------------------------+

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, 86340, CAST('2018-09-05' AS DATETIME)) AS [InDatetimeWithDate];

+-------------------------+
|   InDatetimeWithDate    |
+-------------------------+
| 2018-09-05 23:59:00.000 |
+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

USE below query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @Column_Name)
FROM Table;
```